# I want fill the blank values of the columns based on the same column values in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, contains

```
Name             Code
Ramesh           1234
Ramesh kumar       
Suresh           4532
Sur
```

This is the sample data ,if name contains similar string it should populate the code

Expected result:

```
Name             Code
Ramesh           1234
Ramesh kumar     1234 
Suresh           4532
Sur              4532
```

[image]

Comment: Be more specific. How many characters would be the smallest to be considered as a name? For example would "Sur" be considered like "Suresh" or another name?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not match your example and your two examples do not match. Here is an answer assuming that your first example is actually what you want - that you want to match the first three letters of the names to the code. Matching names can be a lot more complicated if you have many similar names, so this is not a particularly general solution, but it works for your example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#   Create test dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ramesh','Ramesh kumar','Suresh','Sur'],
                     'Code':[1234,np.nan,4532,np.nan]})

#   Create dictionary that maps first three letters of Name to value in Code
dfmap = test[~np.isnan(test['Code'])]
dictmap = {x['Name'][:3]:x['Code'] for i,x in dfmap.iterrows()}

#   Map the first three letters of the name to a new column
test['mapping'] = test['Name'].str[:3].map(dictmap)

#   Write over nans in the Code column with the values in the new column
test.loc[np.isnan(test['Code']),'Code'] = test.loc[np.isnan(test['Code']),'mapping']

#   Remove temporary mapping column
test = test.drop(columns='mapping')
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example and without further explanation, the `.ffill()` method could be enough:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Ramesh', 'Ramesh Kumar', 'Ram', 'Sur', 'Suresh Kumar', 'Suresh'],
                   'code' : [123,np.NaN,np.NaN,456,np.NaN,np.NaN]
                   }))
df['filled'] = df.code.ffill(axis = 0)
df
```

| index | name | code | filled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ramesh | 123.0 | 123.0 |
| 1 | Ramesh Kumar | NaN | 123.0 |
| 2 | Ram | NaN | 123.0 |
| 3 | Sur | 456.0 | 456.0 |
| 4 | Suresh Kumar | NaN | 456.0 |
| 5 | Suresh | NaN | 456.0 |